# what determines the jvm "old space" used at application startup?

Tags: java, unix, jvm

If I increase the -xmx size the old space used at the application startup also increases.  Shouldn't it be the same regardless if I increased the overall heap or not since the application size did not change.

Comment: What does "old space" mean?

Comment: "old space" is also known as "old gen".  sometimes referred to as tenured space.

Answer (score 0):

The -xmx flag sets the maximum size of the heap. Without more specific flags, such as NewSize, the default ratio between old generation to young generation is approximately 2:1. This also means that each partition in the young generation will have different sizes as well, maybe resulting in different objects being promoted/garbage collected. So depending on what kind of data your application loads on startup, changing the overall heap size may result in different overall heap usage at the end of startup.